# Spring Boot app with Maven showing "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException" on first run after project creation

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, visual-studio-code, classnotfoundexception

I am using VSCode with the following relevant extensions: Red Hat, Maven For Java, Spring Boot Extension pack, Spring Boot Tools and Spring Initializr Java Support.

After I have created the Spring Boot project (using Java 11) with Spring Initializr and try to run the program from the main application, I get the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.jk.rekrychat.RekrychatApplication
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jk.rekrychat.RekrychatApplication
```

I don't understand why the program is unable to find the class. I've tried to google the problem and try the solutions, such as: re-create the project, check that the main class is in the correct folder, change the dependencies, check that the launch.json has the correct info, mess with Maven by running package, install and clean, check that I have the correct java version installed. I still get this message everytime. Another Spring Boot Maven project that I downloaded works fine, so the problem must be with this project.

Here's the pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.jk</groupId>
    <artifactId>rekrychat</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>rekrychat</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Here's the main application:

```
package com.jk.rekrychat;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class RekrychatApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RekrychatApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Please note that I have not changed anything after the initial project creation, and I have tried to follow different tutorials on creating the project. Still always the same error.

I'm new to Spring Boot, so any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Also forgot to mention that I'm building the project to .jar

Comment: So how do you run it? please write the complete command line

Comment: Have you tried to run from command line it with: `mvn spring-boot:run` from your project's pom directory?

Comment: @pleft I changed the command to .\mvnw spring-boot:run and it worked, thank you! Before this I tried to run it from the IDE (clicking on the run button in the main class). Do you know why this command worked but running from IDE didn't? In other projects running from the IDE worked fine.

Comment: Sometimes cache would stop the project showing the right result. You can try `Java: Clean Java Language Server Workspace` from command palette.